# PHP return true if all method calls inside a foreach method return true

Tags: php

I am stuck with a problem using foreach essentially my method should return true if the IF statement inside the foreach loop returns true however the problem is that the statement only executes for the first element in the array not the whole array. I tried searching but I cant find a clear answer for my problem. Here is my code snippet

```
public function SaveDisplayOrder($aUnitCustomField)
{
    var_dump($aUnitCustomField);
    foreach($aUnitCustomField as $pUnitCustomField)
    {
      if (CUnitCustomFieldsTable::SaveUnitCustomField($pUnitCustomField))
      {
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So this returns if the `SaveUnitCustomField` method returns true for the first element of `$aUnitCustomField` and stops the execution, how can I check `SaveUnitCustomField` for the whole  `$aUnitCustomField` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what's better than "something failed"? "These specific things failed" so you can actually take action.

```
public function SaveDisplayOrder( $aUnitCustomField ) {
    $returnValue = true;
    $errors = [];
    foreach( $aUnitCustomField as $pUnitCustomField ) {
        if ( ! CUnitCustomFieldsTable::SaveUnitCustomField($pUnitCustomField) )   {
            $returnValue = false;
            $errors[] = "Error when saving $pUnitCustomField";
        }
    }
    return [$returnValue, $errors];
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would change is the presence of an empty error array is enough to determine the state of `returnValue`, I would also add a key with the field name.  But for sure an array of errors is the way to go...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I'd rather have the whole thing driven by Exceptions. Complex return types like what I just wrote feel dirty by comparison.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for the solution this kind of works but I had to use array_push to insert values in `$errors` and also first declare `$errors = array();` and I returned by pushing the `$returnValue` and `$errors` into a new array. Not sure if this is a issue because I am using PHP 5.3

Comment: You could also write the errors to `$this->errors` rather than returning an array like that. Just a thought.